# Purge Command Can Be Used By Anyone

Tags: discord.py

I have created a "clear" function and it has ctx.channel.purge() but it seems like anyone can use it with out any permission.

Any idea on how can I prevent it?
I only want that only members that have the permission manage channeles to be able to use it

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Please take the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look at the [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use the @commands.has_permissions() decorator:

```
@bot.command() # or @commands.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def clear(ctx: commands.Context):
        ctx.channel.purge()
```

Comment: But if he doesn't have permission, the bot won't say anything

Comment: You need to use the command error handler in that case with the decorator `@clear.error`. Then handle the `MissingPermissions` exception inside the method. This is meant to be used inside Cog by the way.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612) is a nice example to give you some overview.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@commands.has_role()` or `@commands.has_permissions()` to allow a specific role or permission to use that command.

**With `commands.has_role`:**

```py
@commands.has_role('Role name') # or you can use role id
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
```

**With `commands.has_permissions`:**

```py
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
```

Or you can use `commands.has_any_role()`. If member has any of these roles that you input as an parameter, they are allowed to execute this command.

```py
@commands.has_any_role('Role1', 'Role2')
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
```

Comment: thanks, but  if he doesn't have permission, the bot won't say anything

Comment: You can use [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.on_command_error) event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `@commands.has_role()` or `@commands.has_permissions()`. Like it says, `@commands.has_role()` checks if the user has a role, and `@commands.has_permissions()` checks if the user has a permission, like read messages, send messages, manage server, etc.